Run SonarQube scan on Flutter web from Github Actions
I'm looking for a way to run a SonarQube Scan on a Flutter web app from github actions.
I've tried adding a step in the build job of my .yml file, and also adding a new job after the build and deploy.
...
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions :
      contents: read
      packages : write
      id-token : write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          flutter-version: '3.19.4'
          channel: 'stable'
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter build web --release
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - uses: sonarsource/sonarqube-scan-action@master
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}

But i keep getting this error message :
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution org.buildobjects.process.StartupException: Could not startup process 'flutter analyze --no-fatal-warnings --no-fatal-infos'.
And a few lines later ...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "flutter" (in directory "/github/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
I know there's a plugin to use SonarQube with flutter, but it doesn't seem to work with github actions either..

You have two checkout steps. Remove the second one. Add its fetch-depth: 0 to the first and run the workflow again.

The error message indicates that the GitHub Actions runner is unable to locate the Flutter executable (flutter) during the execution of the SonarQube scan. This typically occurs because the Flutter SDK is not installed on the GitHub Actions runner machine.
To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that the Flutter SDK is installed before running the SonarQube scan. You can achieve this by adding a setup step to install Flutter in your GitHub Actions workflow file (.yml).
Here's how you can modify your workflow file to include the installation of Flutter:

Thank you for your reply. I made the change and restarted, but I still get the same error message

Install Flutter
  - name: Install Flutter
    uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
    with:
      flutter-version: '3.19.4'
      channel: 'stable'


Actually i'm already installing the flutter SDK, it's even the first step of my build job

I have the same problem here. Here's the yml I'm using:
jobs:
  sonar:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: stable
          flutter-version: 3.x
      - name: Add Flutter to PATH
        run: echo "$HOME/flutter/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
      - name: Install Flutter dependencies
        run: flutter pub get
      - name: Analyze code
        run: flutter analyze
      - name: Run tests
        run: flutter test --coverage > tests. Output 
      - uses: sonarsource/sonarqube-scan-action@master
        with:
          projectBaseDir: ./
          args: >
            -Dsonar.projectKey=${{ secrets.project_key }}
            -Dsonar.sources=lib,pubspec.yaml
            -Dsonar.tests=test
            -Dsonar.exclusions=**/*/*.g.dart
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.sonar_token }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ inputs.sonar_host_url }}


This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

if you think sonarqube is the issue... try a self hosted sonarqube via GHA from sonarless
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions :
      contents: read
      packages : write
      id-token : write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          flutter-version: '3.19.4'
          channel: 'stable'
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter build web --release
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Sonarless Scan
        uses: gitricko/sonarless@v1.1

By default, it will use gitroot as source. You can have an optional sonar-project.properties in git-root for your configurations
Use this to check if it has something to do with your remote server
